# Why does using a variable as a function parameter cause a type mismatch error in a later function call?

Tags: nushell

```
def make-list [val?: string] {
    ["f1" "f2"]
}

def use-list [list: list] {
    $list | each { |it| $it + "!" }
}

let $val = "abc"
let $l = (make-list $val)
use-list $l
```

In this code, I have two functions, one to make a list, and another to consume that list. For the purposes of this MRE, `make-list` returns a simple hard-coded list, and `use-list` prints each element with an exclamation mark added to the end.

If this script executes correctly, it should print a list with two elements "f1!" and "f2!".

`make-list` has an *optional* parameter. In the code above, I create a `$val` variable, then pass that into `make-list`, and store the result of the pipeline to `$l`. Executing `$l | describe` instead of `use-list $l` prints `list<string>`, so I'm confident that `$l` is indeed a list.

The code above throws the following compile error:

```
Error: nu::parser::type_mismatch (link)

  × Type mismatch.
    ╭─[/.../test.nu:10:1]
 10 │ let $l = (make-list $val)
 11 │ use-list $l
    ·          ─┬
    ·           ╰── expected List(Any), found String
    ╰────
```

However, I can modify the `let $l ...` line to allow the script to compile and execute correctly. **Both** of these options will allow the script to compile and returns the expected result.

- The parameter for `make-list` can be removed (because the parameter is optional).

  ```
  let $l = (make-list)
  ```
- The parameter for `make-list` can be replaced by a string literal

  ```
  let $l = (make-list "abc")
  ```

I don't understand why using a *variable* as a parameter call is suddenly causing a type issue with the `use-list` function call. What am I doing wrong here?

---

As an interesting side note, and this might explain the "...found String" part of the error message, if I change the `make-list` parameter to an `int`:

```
def make-list [val?: int] {
    ["f1" "f2"]
}

# ...

let $val = 3
let $l = (make-list $val)
use-list $l
```

It will fail to compile with the same *kind* of error, but the "found" type will reflect the updated parameter type.

```
Error: nu::parser::type_mismatch (link)

  × Type mismatch.
    ╭─[/.../test.nu:10:1]
 10 │ let $l = (make-list $val)
 11 │ use-list $l
    ·          ─┬
    ·           ╰── expected List(Any), found Int
    ╰────
```

Tested using Nushell version 0.74.0 and 0.75.0 on Arch Linux and Windows 11, respectively.

Comment: Just came to my attention that if you **don't** use a subexpression when binding `$l`, it also works just fine: `let $val = "abc"; let $l = make-list $val; use-list $l`

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to "go wrong" with the variable binding. Your scenario does work if the literal string is being evaluated in a [subexpression](https://www.nushell.sh/book/variables_and_subexpressions.html) before it is being bound:

```bash
let $val = ("abc")
# or
let $val = do { "abc" }
```

Even a seemingly useless type casting later on does the trick:

```bash
let $val = "abc"
let $l = (make-list ($val | into string))
```

This is also consistent with other types. Adapting your `int` example:

```bash
def make-list [val?: int] { … }
…
let $val = 123    # fails
let $val = (123)  # works
```

Likewise, having a `do` closure, or type-casting using `into int`, do work as well.

---

Not of importance, however, is the syntax of the variable binding. With the `$` sign omitted, all examples from above still work or fail under the same circumstances, e.g.:

```bash
let val = "abc"    # fails
let val = ("abc")  # works
```

As expected, using `let l =` instead of `let $l =` also yields the same results.